# Authentication in Laravel 5.1.11 - it keeps using default 'User' model and searching 'users' tab

Tags: authentication, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I've created a custom user model, with a custom protected $table name. 
But the attempt method in the controller keeps searching and using the default one ('User' model and 'users' tab)
The weird part is that in Laravel 5.2 it works.
Maybe it's just me that I've missed a stupid thing, but why does it not work on 5.1?
Thanks for your time.

***Model:***

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CustomUser extends Model
{
    protected $table ='myuserstab';
}
```

***Controller:***

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Auth;
use App\CustomUser;

class loginController extends Controller
{

    public function login(Request $request)
    {

        $username= $request['username'];
        $password = $request['password'];
        if(Auth::attempt(['username'=>$username, 'password'=>$password]))
        {
          doSomething...
        }
        else 
        {
         doSomethingelse...
        }
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to change the settings in `config/auth.php`

```
return [

    'driver' => 'eloquent',

    // change this to App\CustomUser::class, or 
    'model' => App\User::class,whatever your model namespace is

     // change this to 'myuserstab'
    'table' => 'users',

];
```

Worth reading this from the docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#introduction-database-considerations

5.2 supports multiple auth providers so perhaps you were able to have both working there? If you look at the config file in 5.2 you see the following:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],
```

You may want to consider the implications of using your own custom model for authentication as the User model is set up to do a lot of things out of the box that you may need to work out yourself. Looking through the docs should clarify such considerations for you.

Comment: Thanks. The 5.2 multi auth thing was my first doubt, but I've decided to ask it anyway just to see if someone had a "smart trick" to make it works without changing the config file... but yeah I guess it's impossible due to the config file itself.
If someone is interested into multi auth in 5.1, I suggest [this article](http://sarav.co/blog/multiple-authentication-in-laravel/)

Comment: Np. Oh I see. To be honest there may be some smart tricks out there so may be worth looking if you didn't find the right solution yet.